# Azure Data Factory - How to read only new files from blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I have a "Continuous Export" process in my Application Insights that create new files based in my new Insights.

Beside that I have a process, using Azure Data Factory, to load one SQL Table with the Blob Storage data.

**The problem:**
I cannot read from A.D.F., only new files from Blob Storage and I'm always processing the same data. At this moment I'm ignoring repeated data after the load process in a SQL Stored Procedure but I want to make this process more efficient by reading only new data from blob storage, can I do this from A.D.F.?
Can anyone help me? Which are the alternatives to achieve this?

Best Regards,
Rui Fernandes

Comment: Data Factory works well with time based folders and has functions to help with this - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-functions-variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which are the alternatives to achieve this?

If WebJob is acceptable, we could do that with WebJob blob trigger easily. We could get more info about WebJob trigger from Azure [official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to)

Following is demo code:

```
 public static void ProcessBlobTrigger([BlobTrigger("containername/{name}")] TextReader input, TextWriter log)
        {
            // your logic to process data
        }
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this option but I followed it because It's the only to achieve what I wanted. Thanks Tom

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend you to archive old blobs programmatically (custom pipeline) by renaming them to "Archive/oldBlobName"! After you do that, when iterating over segmented blob result next time (list of blobs contained in a container you specified in the dataset) in your code, just escape the ones whose name starts with "Archive".

```
        foreach (IListBlobItem listBlobItem in blobList.Results)
        {
            CloudBlockBlob inputBlob = listBlobItem as CloudBlockBlob;

            // Take all blobs from container that are not in "Archive"
            if ((inputBlob == null) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputBlob.Name)
                            || inputBlob.Name.ToLower().StartsWith("Archive"))
            {
                continue;
            }
                     ...
```